# I can't see "Insert New List" in the ribbon

Tags: 2013, ribbon

I cannot see the option Insert -> New List in the ribbon in sharepoint 2013.

Has this function disappeared from the ribbon or is it just a configuration issue?
If it's disappeared, how can i replicate the functionality?

UPDATED

In SP2010 you had the option Insert -> New List in the group Webparts, i'm assuming that group is now Parts, but i cannot see that option anymore.

[image]

Comment: You mean Creating a new list item? Its named as "New Item" in the ribbon.

Comment: No, when i'm in a page. In SP2010 you had the option Insert -> New List in the webpart group

Comment: I get what you are talking about, as far as I can tell, this has been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this option was removed in 2013, it was introduced in 2010, but now to add the list you have to follow the 2 steps of creating it then add it to your page.

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it directly, i see that I'll have to created first a then insert it on the page

Answer (score 1):

In 2013, for adding a list view webpart you can choose

1. Insert -> Then click on "Web Part"
2. This will bring up the tree view, from that you can select the list

[image]

Comment: The thing is... I want to create the list from there not to bring a list that is already created

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Link](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-list-93883178-8139-456f-aaec-bbb7f2dbee29)

You can also create a list by Site contents -> Add an app -> Custom List

Comment: That tutorial is for SP2010... I'm working on SP2013.
Also i'm looking a way to create the list directly from the page as you could do it in SP2010... creating a list from the gear icon -> Add an app -> Custom list it'll move you to another place instead of keeping editing the page, it'll move you to site contents. This is not what i'm looking for